# cannot import name 'ESMForMaskedLM' from 'transformers' on Google colab

Tags: python, bioinformatics, huggingface-transformers, fasta

I am fine tuning the ESM facebook transformer with a fasta file of sequences. However, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'ESMForMaskedLM' from 'transformers'`when running the cell, I have been following: [the hugging face model](https://huggingface.co/facebook/esm-1b) but I haven't managed to make the import work, I am using Google Colab. Help is much appreciated:

the code:

```
!pip install transformers
from transformers import ESMForMaskedLM, ESMTokenizer, pipeline
tokenizer = ESMTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/esm-1b", do_lower_case=False)
model = ESMForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("facebook/esm-1b")
unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
unmasker('QERLKSIVRILE<mask>SLGYNIVAT')
```

Comment: ESM is not yet part of transformers. You can follow the progress [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/13662).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esm is now added to hugging face, use this:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, EsmForMaskedLM, pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/esm2_t6_8M_UR50D")
model = EsmForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("facebook/esm2_t6_8M_UR50D")

unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
g = unmasker('MQIFVKTLTGKTITLEVEPS<mask>TIENVKAKIQDKEGIPPDQQRLIFAGKQLEDGRTLSDYNIQKESTLHLVLRLRGG')
```